# Send all emails to Shop Manager along with admin

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to be able to send all the emails that are sent to admin like new order, out of stock, comments, post publishing, new account registration, posts approval, account approval, password change etc to the shop manager as well. That means I want to treat my Shop Manager as a second admin in my Wordpress or Woocommerce website but with limited capabilities. I researched over this a lot but couldn't find any solution so far. Is there any way we can replicate all outgoing emails (sent to admin) to the Shop Manager in parallel ? Please help me out on this.

Comment: Can't you just add them via WooCommerce -> Settings -> Mail as an additional recipient? The input should support a comma separated list

Comment: I tried but in vain. The input does not support a comma separated list. That's why I am a bit worried.

Comment: I don't have a solution for directly in WC/WP, but as a temporary fix, you could just set up an email forwarding rule in your admin email account to automatically forward emails from your site to the shop manager's email so you both get them.

Comment: How about hooking into `pre_wp_mail` and adding the email that you want, all WordPress mails relay on this function so if you hook into it you could add another email that will receive EVERYTHING, just make sure that that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind sharing the example code of its usage ?